# Manage a boolean value

Tags: javascript, angular

In my hmtl I would to show an alert based on value of variable.

so I have in my html:

```
<div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col col-12 col-md-12 configurator-form-input">
                            <div *ngIf="showingUpdateMessage === true" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                Success.
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="showingUpdateMessage === false" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                Danger
                            </div>
                        </div>
 </div>
```

<button (click)="onUpdateCustomer(form)">Save

So in my component.ts

```
export class Page implements OnInit {
    showingUpdateMessage: boolean

updateFunction(form){
 this.showingUpdateMessage = null
 this.service.updateForm(form).subscribe(
 (data) => { this.showingUpdateMessage = true},
 (error) => { this.showingUpdateMessage = false}
 )
}
```

}

So my problem is that sometimes the alert  doesn't appear, so I tried to inizialize the variable to null in the function. But I notice that sometimes alert doesn't show up.

How can I manage a boolean variable, that will be set ,for example, in response to an api call?

Comment: Are you using reactive forms ?

Comment: hey , yes i'm using

Comment: Then I would suggest you use formErrors accordingly.

Comment: But my alert depending on the api call

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is using a boolean like this when you have a reactive form available. You could even go as far as creating a custom async validator. In short : learn more about how reactive forms work.

Answer (score -1):

You have a change detection issue. Just add this to your code.

```js
constructor(
  // ...
  private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

//..

updateFunction(form){
  this.showingUpdateMessage = null
  this.service.updateForm(form).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.cdRef.detectChanges())
  ).subscribe(
    (data) => { this.showingUpdateMessage = true},
    (error) => { this.showingUpdateMessage = false}
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can store the `Observable` itself inside the variable and use `async pipe` in the template - this is a better practice

```
this.showingUpdateMessage$ = this.service.updateForm(form).pipe(mapTo(true));
```

and inside your template:

```
<div class="col col-12 col-md-12 configurator-form-input" *ngIf="showingUpdateMessage$ | async as showUpdateMessage">
                        <div *ngIf="showUpdateMessage" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            Success.
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="!showUpdateMessage" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            Danger
                        </div>
                    </div>
```